# Making text same size on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, text-size, hdpi

I wonder how to make application look the same on different devices. I have read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) many times but I still can't understand how to live.

Here is a sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is Galaxy S II (480x800) and Sensation XE (540x960). They are both `hdpi`, physical screen size is almost the same. I expected to see the same looking on both devices but in fact text on 540x960 is smaller then on 480x800:
[image]
(left is 480x800, right is 540x960)

I tried to specify text size as dimension resource and make separate folder `values-w540dp` but it took no effect.

How do you guys make your application look the same on different `hdpi` devices?

Comment: Technically those 2 things are equal.  It can make the text the same size, but it can't make the smaller screen wider :)  Notice how "Hello" ends roughly in the same spot on the end of "Demo"?

Answer (score 3):

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

These atributes may solve your problem here.Otherwise you have to setup your layout dynamically with some ratios(or factors you generate like :textSize=factor*height) using your screen height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [metrics](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) , if you specify your textsize in dp (Density-independent pixels) it should work. The default size for text should be around 14dp. (TextAppearance.small)

Answer (score 0):

2 Sites that might be helpful as there are some nuggets in both related to your problem, however, neither is an exact 1-2-3 how to correct the issue you're seeing:

- http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/08/deep-dive-into-responsive-mobile-design-part-1.html
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/